# Should I repeat -san to refer to someone whos name ends in san?

Tags: honorifics

My friend's name is Allisan, how can I make it clear that her name is オーリサン and the honorific 'san' is not included and furthermore how can she introduce herself without sounding like a smug to everyone?

Comment: You can add -san to someones name even if it ends in san. For example; オーリサンさん。 If you want to make it clearer when talking, an extremely slight pause between the name and the -san the first time you introduce them, would add emphasis though is not normally required.

Comment: Are you trying to transcribe (?) her name to オーリサン, or is that how she's always written it?  Because it would more likely just be アリソン.

Comment: [「俺の名前はハッサンだ!呼び捨てで構わないからな」「じゃぁよろしくね♪ハッ!」](http://matome.naver.jp/odai/2138684108815867001/2138684548221852103)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In ***self-introductions***, 「さん」 is ***NEVER*** attached to the name in the first place.  I have seen quite a few beginning Japanese-learners attaching it to their own names, but that is completely improper.  They seem to mistakenly think that it is ***polite*** to attach 「さん」 to their own names when, in fact, you attach it only to ***other people's names***.

Other people can address your friend as 「オーリサンさん」 with no problems whatsoever.  It ***is*** the proper way.  That it might sound funny is besides the point.

In self-introductions, your friend can say:

「オーリサンです。」、「オーリサンと[言]{い}います。」、「オーリサンと[申]{もう}します。」, etc.

and no Japanese-speakers would think that the "san" part is an honorific.  This, I can promise as a Japanese-speaker.

I have personally addressed people as 「イーサンさん」、「ネイサンさん」, etc.  When pronounced with the right intonation, these do not sound nearly as funny as you might think.

Comment: I know foreigners mistakenly use honorifics and attach it to themselves. I've also seen egotistical characters use honorifics on themselves which is the reason for this question. But yes I suppose that should clarify it.